# HTML/CSS: How to prevent DIV scrollbar going off screen?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position, overflow

It seems there are a few StackOverflow posts about this issue,
but I still cannot fix the problem.

So, I am providing the very exact HTML/CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/dbaroncelli/r08qfcv2/2/

[image]

As you can see, the scrollbar is shown in its own length when it's at the top.

But when you scroll to the bottom, part of the scrollbar gets hidden, as well as the bottom part of the text.

How can you solve this issue, so that the bottom of the text doesn't get hidden?

This is the CSS, which you also find in the Fiddle link above:

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.topdiv {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.scrolldiv {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of solutions, but the best one is probably to use CSS Grid, though do check if your target browser supports it (IE is the only problematic one these days really).

The CSS should look something like this:

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.topdiv {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.scrolldiv {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: yellow;
}
```

I've offset the borders of the body just to make clearer the position of the elements.The key line is probably `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;` This means that the grid consists of two rows. The first row contains your red header. `auto` means that the height will adjust automatically for the contents of this. `1fr` means that the second row will take up the remainder of the height of the grid.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/oz1ueh7g/) is a working JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like also in your solution the bottom of the text gets hidden: https://jsfiddle.net/dbaroncelli/d3bhp71L/1/

Comment: I think that's an issue with JS Fiddle. Or perhaps I haven't understood the question.

Comment: Hi, you are right! it's actually just an issue of JSFiddle! On a browser it works, and actually it doesn't even need `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr`. It seems enough to specify `display: grid`. Many thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. :)